# Capture prefix or suffix or both

Tags: regex

I have regex with capture groups `(^A)(B)(C$)`

I want to match:

```
(^A)(B)(C$) or
(^A)(B) or
^(B)(C$)
```

Basically not (B) by itself. I'm looking through lookahead, lookbehind, atomic groups and can't figure out how to apply.

EDIT:

```
Group A: ^([Ww]\d+\.?\d*)?

Group B: (([Xx]\d+)([Yy]\d+)?)

Group C: ([Zz]\d+)?$
```

I want to capture

```
w10x10y10z10
w10x10z10
w10x10
x10y10z10
x10z10
```

just not

```
x10
x10y10
```

by itself

Comment: Do you mean you want to match a whole string that can be `B`, `AB`, `BC` or `ABC`? Try `^(A)?(B)(C)?$`

Comment: Sorry reply is a mess, update original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a condition to avoid matching just `B` or `BC` patterns with the help of a negative lookahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?!x\d+(?:y\d+)?$)(\d+\.?\d*)?((x\d+)(y\d+)?)(z\d+)?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kaMZfS/2) (**Note**: use case insensitive modifier with this regex version).

The `(?!x\d+(?:y\d+)?$)` lookahead basically fails the match once it matches `x`, 1+ digits and then an optional sequence of `Y` and 1+ digits followed with the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the string you try to match have 4 groups:

```
w: w\d+
x: x\d+
y: y\d+
z: z\d+
```

The group trying to capture is:

```
wxyz
wxz
wx
wxy
xyz
xz
wz
w
z
```

but not

```
x
y
xy
```

The regex can do the job: `((?<=w\d+)|(?=z\d+))(x\d+)?(y\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A` is the string head, `C` is the string tail and `B` is somthing in the middle of the string.

```
/^AB|BC$/
```

If `B` is too complicated, we can rethink the meaning of `B` as follows:

```
/^AB1|B2C$/
```

where `A` and `C` have the same sense. `B1` refers to the beginning of the middle substring and `B2` refers to its ending.